# Hem server serving nothing

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I'm trying to get started with spine.js following the steps here:

http://spinejs.com/docs/started

When i call `hem server` as documented i get the following response:

```
Starting server on: 9294
```

If i then visit http://localhost:9294 I get nothing, occasionally a completely blank document. If I check my system processes node is running, so I'm assuming the server is actually running. If i call `hem build` then it seems to build ok.

Could this have something to do with the fact that i'm running xampp at the same time?

This is happening on windows xp and 7.

Comment: You might try running `Spine.js` not on Hem, but on `Brunch`: http://brunch.io/#documentation, just grab `spine.js` skeleton and run something like `brunch w -s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that the same thing happens without XAMPP running on Win7.

But per Alex, Windows is not supported. :(

https://github.com/maccman/hem/issues/23